# How to automate Kubernetes configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I would like to automate my Kubernetes configuration, like Ansible for VMs.

A sample scenario:

1. Create namespace harbor
2. Deploy Harbor via Helm https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm

What kind tool is suitable for such as scenario? Can I also use terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally agree with *@P Ekambaram* that **kubernetes automation** can be successfully done with **ansible** but at the same time I totally disagree with him when it comes to the way it should be done. Such *"declarative"* code isn't actually declarative at all. It turns into a mere wrapper for the set of imperative commands. Apart from that such playbook isn't [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html) (let's remind that *an operation is idempotent if the result of performing it once is exactly the same as the result of performing it repeatedly without any intervening actions*.). This approach is contrary to one of the key concepts present in **ansible**.

`shell` or `command` modules should be used in **ansible** as last resort modules, only if there is no other way of performing required task e.g. when dedicated module doesn't exist or lacks some important functionalities.

When it comes to **automating kubernetes with ansible**, such dedicated modules already exist.

Take a quick look at [k8s - ansible module for managing kubernetes objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#k8s-manage-kubernetes-k8s-objects) and you'll see that the desired results can be achieved in much more elegant and clearer way:

**namespace creation:**

```
- name: Create a k8s namespace
  k8s:
    name: testing
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present
```

**creating service based on yaml definition file**

```
- name: Create a Service object by reading the definition from a file
  k8s:
    state: present
    src: /testing/service.yml
```

Have you just mentioned you're using **helm** for managing your **kubernetes** applications ? Take a look at [helm module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/helm_module.html). Any examples ? Here you are:

```
- name: Install helm chart from a git repo
  helm:
    host: localhost
    chart:
      source:
        type: git
        location: https://github.com/user/helm-chart.git
    state: present
    name: my-example
    namespace: default
```

#### update:

To be able to run most **Ansible** modules on a certain host, you need to have installed on it two things:

- python 2.7
- ssh server

While it is true for most modules, some of them have additional requirements that must be met before the module can be run on such host.

When it comes to `k8s` module, as we can read in the its [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#requirements):

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this
>   module.
>
> ```
> python >= 2.7
> openshift >= 0.6
> PyYAML >= 3.11
> ```

It isn't true that it requires **openshift** (different kubernetes implementation). It wouldn't make much sense to install **openshift** to manage workload of our **kubernetes cluster**. So let's be precise to avoid spreading any potentially misleading information: It requires [**OpenShift python client library**](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python) and it requires it to be installed on the host, on which the module is run (i.e. on the host on which we normally run our `kubectl` commands).

> The OpenShift Python client wraps the K8s Python client, providing
>   full access to all of the APIS and models available on both platforms.
>   For API version details and additional information visit
>   https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python

**Important!:** you don't have to install any additional modules on your kubernetes nodes. You need them only on the machine from which you manage your **kubernetes workload**.

If we have our **Ansible** installed on the same host on which we have configured our `kubectl` tool and we want to run our playbooks on it directly without a need of using **ssh** or configuring **ansible inventory**, we simply need to refer to it in our **ansible playbook** as:

```
hosts: localhost
connection: local
```

The whole playbook for creating new k8s namespace may look like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Create a k8s namespace
    k8s:
      name: testing
      api_version: v1
      kind: Namespace
      state: present
```

And we can run it by simply executing:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

Before we can do that, however, we need to make sure we have all required dependencies installed which in fact arn't so many and they limit to **python 2.7** and **two above mentioned libraries** (in required versions).

Once you have **Python** installed on your host, the easiest way to install the rest of the required dependencies is by runnig:

```
pip install openshift
```

and

```
pip install PyYAML
```

You may encounter the following error:

```
"msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on ***** Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
```

If so, running:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

should fix it (at least it fixed it in my case) and after that our simple **ansible playbook** which creates new `namespace` in our **kubernetes cluster** should run smoothly. :)

Comment: Unfortunately there are lot of unneccessay dependencies for using such modules like k8s for example openshift!

Comment: Does it extst a tutorial for K8S with ansible

Comment: Not so many however I totally understand that this might not be the solution for everyone. [Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_kubernetes.html) you have described all the requirements.

Comment: @zero_coding, to be honest I didn't find any tutorial that I could really recommend on managing kubernetes workload using ansible. Most of them are rather about setting up the whole kubernetes cluster as ansible can be also a good choice for automating it. But I think [the official documentation of the module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) explains it well enough to get started. Btw. what are your reasons to automate it? Creating namespace and applying single helm chart are just two simple steps so in my opinion using ansible for it is a bit of overkill.

Comment: @mario the last question, how connect ansible to kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @zero_coding, please see my recent **update**. I hope everything is clearly explained.